# error: constructor Name2 in class Name2 cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract, super

while coding I'm encountering the some problem.
In multilevel inheritance, **cl** is variable used in both class A and B, but when running the program its showing error. Im pasting code below.

```
     class Name{
    int cl=0;
}
class Name2 extends Name{
    public Name2(int cl)
    {
        this.cl=cl;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.valueOf(cl);
    }
}
class Name3 extends Name2{
    int tl;
    public Name3(int cl,int tl)
    {
        super();
        this.tl=tl;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.valueOf(cl);
    }
}

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Name3 obj=new Name3(3,6);

        System.out.println(obj);
     }
}



  ----------------------------------

Output is:

    > $javac HelloWorld.java HelloWorld.java:18: error: constructor Name2 in
    > class Name2 cannot be applied to given types;
    >         super();
    >         ^   required: int   found: no arguments   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length 1 error
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you need to pass an int argument to the super() in construtor.

```
public Name3(int cl,int tl)
    {
        super(cl);
        this.tl=tl;
    }
```

Comment: Adding the required parameterless constructor in `Name2` is an option as well.